# Create Azure AD Tenant from command or API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have been working on creating New Tenant from API or Command Line in Azure Active Directory and I could not find a way to do it.
I have been also using Azure GraphAPI but it doesn't support this.

Is there any way from command or API that I can use to automate creation of new tenants?

I have researched on google and stackoverflow, but I didn't find any way to do it from command or API.
and is there any plan of Microsoft to provide such API in future? (edited)

Answer (score 0):

There's no public, documented or supported (by MSFT) API available for this. That being said you might try using the portal internal API with something like this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/Directories" `
-Method "POST" `
-Headers @{
  "Accept-Language"="en"
  "Authorization"="Bearer <azure ad access token issued for aud=74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6>"
 } `
-ContentType "application/json" `
-Body "{`"companyName`":`"<company name>`",`"initialDomainPrefix`":`"<initial domain prefix (the one that will be appended to onmicrosoft.com)>`",`"countryCode`":`"<iso (2 letter) country code>`"}"
```

Comment: Hello, for what resource is the `74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6` id? I see that this is the same for every tenant. Will it ever change?

Comment: I tried this a number of different ways and got an error message every time.  I'm coming to the conclusion that unfortunately this internal api simply cannot be used for creating a tenant.  Error:


Forbidden({"message":"Forbidden","httpStatusCode":"Forbidden","xMsServerRequestId":null,"clientData":{"errorCode":"MsaUserWithNoAccessToTenant","localizedErrorDetails":null,"operationResults":null,"timeStampUtc":"2021-09-29T21:00:15.2385883Z","clientRequestId":"<guid>","internalTransactionId":"<guid>","tenantId":"<guid>","userObjectId":"<guid>","exceptionType":"Exception"},"stackTrace":null})